# How to force one view controller to display in landscape and the other always stay in portrait

Tags: ios

I thought this would be simple and I've read a ton on how to do this, but nothing works for me. I'm using xcode 5 and ios7.
I have about ten view controllers and I want all of them except one to stay in portrait mode.  I want one of the view controllers to only display in landscape left and then when finished the next or previous view controllers will always revert back to portrait only.
I cannot figure out how to do this.
Any suggestions?  I've read a ton of the stuff posted here, but none of it seems to work for me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `supportedInterfaceOrientations` in your view controller class.  Return

`UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait`

in the one that should stay in portrait orientation.  Return

`UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait`

in the one that can rotate.

Answer (score 1):

In the view controller that you don't want to rotate add:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);

}
```

Comment: shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation was deprecated in iOS 6.  supportedInterfaceOrientations is now the recommended method